# RichTextBox cannot display Unicode Mathematical alphanumeric symbols

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, unicode, richtextbox

I cannot get WinForms `RichTextBox` display some Unicode characters, particularly [Mathematical alphanumeric symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols) (but the problem is most probably not limited to those).

Surprisingly the same characters can display in a plain or multiline `TextBox` using the same (default) font. Even if I change the font to for example "Arial" or "Lucida", I get the same results.

[image: TextBox vs. RichTextBox]

The screenshot is from Windows 10, but I'm getting the same results on Windows 7. The example shows *ascii small a-d* followed by *mathematical italic sans-serif small alpha-delta*.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and .NET 4.6.1.

A trivial test code:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
    this.richTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
    // ...
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // textBox1
    // 
    this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(25, 38);
    this.textBox1.Multiline = true;
    this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
    this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(182, 108);
    this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.textBox1.Text = "abcd ";
    // 
    // richTextBox1
    // 
    this.richTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(213, 38);
    this.richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1";
    this.richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(179, 108);
    this.richTextBox1.TabIndex = 1;
    this.richTextBox1.Text = "abcd ";
    // ...
}
```

---

Note that it does not seem to be a problem with storing the characters. The characters are correctly stored in the `RichTextBox`. If you copy the text out and paste it somewhere (like to the `TextBox`), all characters display correctly.

On the other hand, if you paste the characters to the `RichTextBox`, you get the same incorrect display.

So it looks like a display problem only.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a bug/decision by design in [`RichTextBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) which has been fixed in .NET 4.7.

`RichTextBox` is in fact a wrapper around `RichEdit`. In .NET 4.7, the control is using `RICHEDIT50W` while in previous versions it's using `RichEdit20W`.

To solve the problem you can use either of these options:

- Upgrade to .NET 4.7

OR

- You can use the latest version of `RichTextBox` that is `RICHEDIT50W`, to do so you should inherit from standard `RichTextBox` and override `CreateParams` and load library `Msftedit.dll` and set the `ClassName` to `RICHEDIT50W`.

To see an implementation, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32618479/3110834).

Comment: I changed to 4.7 and now working fine. Thank you so much @Reza Aghaei.

Comment: its still happening in 4.8

Comment: @JadaVonRuth I didn't try recently, but I checked the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RichTextBox.cs,398) of `RichTextBox`, and I expect it work properly. Make sure you haven't truned on the `Switch.System.Windows.Forms.DoNotLoadLatestRichEditControl` in `AppContextSwitchOverrides`.