# Good RTF viewer control

Tags: vb.net, rtf

Someone knows a winform control able to view correctly a standard rtf at least v1.5?
I need something that render correctly header, footer, tables, margins etc. as Winword do.
I don't strictly need to be editable.

Tried Richtextbox and also some ex version but none respected the expected layout.

Comment: Does it work in WordPad? If so, you could try forcing the RichTextBox control to use the latest RichEdit50W version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18668921/3740093

Comment: No, Wordpad doesn't show correctly the tables and miss at all header and footer

Answer (score 0):

well, found the solution here: http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/sites/tx-text-control-express/

Both professional or free editions are available.
The control is great replacement of richtextbox with full featured WYSIWYG editor that support tables, images, etc.

VERY fast also with large documents (tried 300 pages doc with tables)